# Pandas df: Assign index.values to a new empty df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas=1.1.5

I want to assign the index values of df2 to the column of a new empty df.
I tried the below code, but got the error:

**"Must have equal len keys and value "
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable**

```
df= pd.DataFrame()
df[['Name']]=df2.index.values
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC use:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Name': df2.index})
```

Or:

```
df = df2.index.to_frame(name='Name', index=False)
```

Another idea:

```
df= pd.DataFrame()
df['Name']=df2.index
```